# Are these `.` attribute bindings necessary in the implementation of `functools.partial`?

Tags: python, scope, functools

[docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=args#functools.partial) says that `functools.partial` is roughly equivalent to:

```
def partial(func, /, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = {**keywords, **fkeywords}
        return func(*args, *fargs, **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```

*(Note: `/` is used to denote `func` as a positional-only argument of `partial`. See [1].)*

If I understand correctly, when a variable is referenced within a nested function, such as `newfunc`, Python first looks for the variable definition within the nested function. If the definition is not found there, Python will next look for the definition in the enclosing scope (i.e. the outer function; `partial` in this case). So, are the explicit `.func`, `.args`, and `.keywords` attribute bindings to `newfunc` above really necessary? I tried an example without said bindings and it `partial` worked just fine? Is there a case where they might be necessary?

```
def partial(func, /, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = {**keywords, **fkeywords}
        return func(*args, *fargs, **newkeywords)
    # newfunc.func = func
    # newfunc.args = args
    # newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc

# p0, p1, p2 are positional arguments
# kw0, kw1, kw2 are keyword-only arguments
def foo3(p0, p1, p2, *, kw0, kw1, kw2):
    return 100*p2 + 10*p1 + 1*p0, kw0 + kw1 + kw3

foo2 = partial(foo3, 1, kw0=1+1j)

print(foo2(2,3,kw1=2+2j, kw2=3+3j)) # (321, (6+6j))
```

Are the `.` bindings necessary if the `keywords` or `fkeywords` dictionaries includes an item with `func`, `args`, or `keywords` as the keyword? What would be an example where these are necessary? As far as I can tell, that's not a reason because the following works:

```
def partial(func, /, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = {**keywords, **fkeywords}
        return func(*args, *fargs, **newkeywords)
    # newfunc.func = func
    # newfunc.args = args
    # newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc

# p0, p1, p2 are positional arguments
# kw0, kw1, kw2 are keyword-only arguments
def foo3(p0, p1, p2, kw0, kw1, kw2, **kwargs):
    return 100*p2 + 10*p1 + 1*p0, kw0 + kw1 + kw2 + sum(kwargs.values())

foo2 = partial(foo3, 1, kw0=1+1J, func=10, args=10j, keywords=100+100j)

print(foo2(2,3,kw1=2+2J, kw2=3+3J, func=20, args=20j, keywords=200+200j)) # (321, (226+6j))
```

---

[1] https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters

Comment: Notice that `newfunc.func` is an [attribute on the function object](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/); it is not the same thing as the variable `func` inside `newfunc`. However, I must confess I do not know the answer to the obvious follow-up question to this...

Comment: Gotcha. Followup: say we set the attribute on the function object (i.e. `newfunc.func = func`). Then, when `newfunc` makes a reference to `func`,  does which value of `func` does Python use? Does it use `newfunc.func` or `func` as passed into the `partial` function (in this case they are both the same because we did `newfunc.func = func`, but what if we hadn't?)?

Comment: @joseville functions are just objects, you can set arbitrary attributes on objects. There is nothing particularly exotic or special about this, e.g. `class Foo: pass`; then `foo = Foo(); foo.a = 42; foo.b = [1,2,3]` etc etc this doesn't affect anything about the variables referenced in the functions code

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I understand setting attributes on functions now, thanks. Also, I tried to set an arbitrary attribute on a `dict` instance which I think is an object, but that didn't work: `a = {}; a.attr = 1` caused `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'attr'`.

Comment: @joseville yes, certain objects prevent arbitrary attribute setting. Some built-in objects, or objects written as c-extensions, or user-defined classes with `__slots__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can look at the `partial` class implementation to help you understand better.

The following (`Python 3.9.5`)

```py
class partial:
    """New function with partial application of the given arguments
    and keywords.
    """

    __slots__ = "func", "args", "keywords", "__dict__", "__weakref__"

    def __new__(cls, func, /, *args, **keywords):
        if not callable(func):
            raise TypeError("the first argument must be callable")

        if hasattr(func, "func"):
            args = func.args + args
            keywords = {**func.keywords, **keywords}
            func = func.func

        self = super(partial, cls).__new__(cls)

        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.keywords = keywords
        return self

    def __call__(self, /, *args, **keywords):
        keywords = {**self.keywords, **keywords}
        return self.func(*self.args, *args, **keywords)
    
    ...
```

When you replace `self` with `newfunc`, they're pretty much the same.

Comment: Thanks. I understand most of that code, except the significance of `__slots__`, why `__new__` is used instead of `__init__` and why `super` is called, but seems like the reason for the storing the attributes in `self`/`newfunc` is so you can pass a `partial` instance as the `func` into a new `partial` without losing first `partial`'s `func`, `args` and `keywords`. For example, if you do: `partial(partial(foo, 1, b=3), 2, c=4)`, then the first partial's `args` and `keywords` (1 and b=3) respectively) would be concatenated with the second partials `args` and `keywords` (2 and c=4 respectively).

Comment: @joseville Putting the processing in `__new__` into `__init__` has the same effect. As for handling within `__new__` or `__init__` and generating `self` using `super`, maybe this is closer to OOP?
This logic in `hasattr(func, "func")` can be said to process the incoming instance of `partail` to merge the parameters `args` and `kwargs`.
You can think of `self` as `newfunc`, so `newfunc()` can be interpreted as `self()`.

Comment: [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/zh-cn/3.9/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__call__#slots)
[`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/zh-cn/3.9/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__call__#object.__call__)

Comment: The attributes `func`, `args`, and `kwargs` stored in `self` will be used when the instance is called, namely `self()`.